# world position to screen position in fragment shader glsl

Tags: glsl, webgl, fragment-shader, coordinate-transformation

I have a WebGL renderer and I want to transform random world coordinates to screen coordinates in the fragment shaders.

That will allow me to compare the "computed screen coordinates" to the current fragment screen coordinates.

I have all the information needed to do so I believe, just not sure which is the right way to do so.

```
  ...
  // available information:

  // uCanvasWidth (float)
  // uCanvasHeight (float)
  // modelMatrix (mat4)
  // modelViewMatrix (mat4)
  // projectionMatrix (mat4)
  vec4 someWorldCoordinates = vec4(1., 2., 3., 1.);
  // map it to screen coordinates?
  vec4 screenCoordinates = ???

  // compare to current fragment location
  if(screenCoordinates.x > gl_FragCoord.x){
    // do stuff
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vec4 worldSpace = vec4(1., 2., 3., 1.);
// get homogeneous clip space coordinates
vec4 clipSpace = projectionMatrix * ( modelViewMatrix * worldCoords );
// apply perspective divide to get normalized device coordinates
vec3 ndc = clipSpace.xyz / clipSpace.w;
// do viewport transform
vec2 screenSpace = (ndc.xy * .5 + .5) * vec2(uCanvasWidth, uCanvasHeight);
screenSpace.y = uCanvasHeight - screenSpace.y;
```

Note that your `modelView` matrix likely contains the *transforms* of the model you're rendering. I would assume that the points specified in in shader are thought to be already "*final*" world space(as in not relative to the model you're rendering), so you might want to use just the `view` matrix here(preferrably a premultiplied `viewProjection`).

Comment: I think this will give you an inverted `screenSpace.y`.

Comment: should it be `screenSpace = (ndx.xy * .5 + .5) * vec2(viewportWidth, viewportIHeight) + vec2(viewportLeft, viewportRight);`?

Comment: @gman yes that is probably correct and a more generic solution but in my case my viewport is the same size as my canvas!

Comment: @gman Yes the complete viewport transform would be like that(assuming you meant `+vec2(viewportLeft, viewportTop)`.